# Check if a mocked function is being called from within a class method

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I have the following files -

summer.py

```
def sum(a, b):
    return a+b
```

base.py

```
class Base():
    def work(self, a, b):
        self.add(a, b)
```

calculator.py

```
from summer import sum
from base import Base
class Calculator(Base):
    def work(self, a, b):
        super().work(a, b)

    def add(self, a, b):
        return sum(a, b)
```

test_calculator.py

```
from unittest import mock
from calculator import Calculator
@mock.patch('calculator.sum')
def test_calc(mock_sum):
    a = 5
    b = 10
    mock_sum.return_value = 0
    Calculator().work(a, b)
    mock_sum.assert_called_once()
```

However, when I run `test_calculator.py` I get an `AssertionError` as follows -

```
AssertionError: Expected 'mock_sum' to have been called once. Called 0 times.
```

What is the correct way to mock `sum()`?

Comment: What's your Python version. I try in Python 3.6.8, It's OK. You code isn't complete, I just add `import` Clause.

Comment: @hstk my bad, I missed out one part of the code that seems to be causing the issue - the inheritance

Comment: func `test_calc` not inherit the `unittest.TestCase` ?